Can any data be recovered from an SSD after you reset windows?
If you reset your PC (windows reset), and you have a SSD, can anything be recovered?
What difference does choosing the “clean the drive” option make in terms of recovery?
Also, if you quickly turn off your pc after resetting, say a few minutes after, will this change anything?
